# In @font-face CSS rule, can we have a separate 'src' declaration for 'local' definition?

Tags: css, font-face, src

Here's an example @font-face CSS rule:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DroidSerifBoldItalic';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Droid Serif Bold Italic'), local('DroidSerif-BoldItalic'),
       url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Don't you think, the following @font-face CSS rule is better? (As you can see, the browsers, in this case even IE, can first check if the font is available on the user's computer, before downloading it.)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DroidSerifBoldItalic';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Droid Serif Bold Italic'), local('DroidSerif-BoldItalic');
  src: url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('DroidSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Are there any gotchas here? If not, why isn't everyone using the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i know about @font-face, the main fear behind using local is that the font will not be named the same on someone's desktop. You're ceding control there, and if you're wrong it'll fail. You do pose an interesting question though, and i'm not saying you're wrong. You can read more about that [here](http://typophile.com/node/63992) and [here](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/#smiley).

---

**ADDENDUM**

> Normally, it’s used as [a mask to prevent unwanted http requests](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) in IE.

The order matters because IE (at least until IE8) doesn't support the `local` descriptor, and placing the `local` descriptor right after the EOT font format prevents the older versions of Internet Explorer from downloading the other font formats (in the `src` declaration) as they aren't supported, and won't be used anyway.

---

What @BoltClock commented is true. And that's the reason why we use two `local` definitions -- `local('Droid Serif Bold Italic'), local('DroidSerif-BoldItalic'),`. The first is the normal name of the font (which is recognized by all browsers except Safari), and the latter is the PostScript name of the font which is required by Safari (at least on Mac / OS X systems).

To avoid issues like two different fonts (mostly on two different OSs) having the same name, some simply use `local('☺')`.

Comment: Even more annoying is that some browsers may use different family names for a font when matching with `local()`.

Comment: @albert I've found the answer. Check mine below (or above). :)

Comment: you mean i gave you the answer in that link. boo answering your own questions. makes me resent helping you out.

Comment: @albert I am sorry. But I just quoted the text as it is [from this link](http://readableweb.com/google-fonts-failing-for-internet-explorer-users/). I didn't mean to take the credit, I just didn't notice that the source links were the same. :(

Comment: chillax. i overreact at times. glad u got your answer

Comment: @BoltClock it would be great if you could simply merge mine and albert's answer. (I don't want to delete my answer because multiple deletes of my own questions and answers can get me banned).

Comment: @geekpanth3r: I'm unable to merge answers automatically - the best you can do is to edit with a reference to this answer which I see you've done. And as far as I understand, self-deleted answers don't count toward an answer ban as long as you continue to contribute useful content :)

Comment: @albert cheers! Merged my answer with yours. :) You may not see the changes now, not until my edit is approved.

Comment: you're good man. i need to stop being cynical and remember why i'm on here in the first place. 100 apologies. :)

Comment: @albert No problem at all. :)